# Noob who's stuck with e-commerce project shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html, css

For the TL;dr or struggling to understand here's a diagram.[image: screenshots to explain]

Simplifying my question:
I have a home page with some items to add to cart, I have added these items to cart, when I go to the cart page, I want to see these added items to cart on the cart page (HTML code provided below), that is all.

Currently stuck and stressing because my code isn't functioning, the issue I'm having is that I want to get the selected products in the local storage is sent to the cart where the image is placed within the image column and so on with the name, description & quantity etc. But I've run into 100 dead ends and I feel like the more I try the more damage I'm doing to the project.

I know I could simply scrap the HTML and CSS I currently have and start over with javascript and just use ${item.tag} etc. but I want to see if it's functional as it is before I scrap the whole thing.

I've managed to follow through tutorials to write the code that collects the data for selecting products and saving it to basket but now I'm trying to transfer the data to the cart page for checking out.

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

let products = [
    {
        name: 'product 1',
        description: 'test',
        tag: 'citizenwatch',
        price: 5,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Camera Lense',
        description: 'test',
        tag: 'cameralense',
        price: 10,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Shoes & Tie',
        description: 'test',
        tag: 'shoesandtie',
        price: 15,
        inCart: 0
    }
];

for (let i=0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        totalCost(products[i])
    })
}

function onLoadCartNumbers() {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

    if (productNumbers) {
        document.querySelector('.c-cart-toggler-wrapper span').textContent = productNumbers;
    }
}

function cartNumbers(product) {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

    if( productNumbers ) {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector('.c-cart-toggler-wrapper span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1);
        document.querySelector('.c-cart-toggler-wrapper span').textContent = 1;
    }

    setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log("My cartItems are", cartItems);

    if(cartItems != null) {
        if(cartItems[product.tag] == undefined) {
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [product.tag]: product
            }
        }
        cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;
    } else {
        product.inCart = 1;
        cartItems = {
            [product.tag]: product
        }
    }

    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify (cartItems));
}

function totalCost(product) {
    //console.log("The product price is", product.price);
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    console.log("my cartcost is", cartCost);
    console.log(typeof cartCost );

    if(cartCost != null) {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
    }

} 
onLoadCartNumbers();
```

```css
.c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-title,
.c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(135, 151, 174, 0.15); }

.c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row {
  padding: 15px 0; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-item-title {
    margin: 0 15px 20px 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid;
    float: left; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-image {
    position: relative;
    clear: both; }
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-image > img {
      width: 65%; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-desc h3 {
    margin-top: 0; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-remove > .c-cart-remove-desktop {
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 24px; }

.c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: both; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > a {
    display: inline-block; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > .c-cart-float-l {
    float: left; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > .c-cart-float-r {
    float: right; }

.c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-subtotal-border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(135, 151, 174, 0.15); }

.c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-sub-title,
.c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-remove-mobile,
.c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-item-title {
  display: none; }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  /* 991px */
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-table-title,
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-remove-desktop {
    display: none; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-sub-title,
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 .c-cart-remove-mobile {
    display: block; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px -4px #ccc;
    border: none; }
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-item-title {
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: block; }
      .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-item-title.c-cart-item-first {
        margin-top: 0; }
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-ref,
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-qty,
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-price,
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-total {
      margin: 20px 0; }
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-remove {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 20px 0; }
      .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-remove > .c-cart-remove-mobile {
        display: inline-block; } }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* 767px */
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-image > img {
    width: 100%; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-ref,
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-price,
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-table-row > .c-cart-remove {
    clear: both; } }

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /* 480px */
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > a:last-child {
      margin: 0; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > .c-cart-float-l {
    float: none; }
  .c-shop-cart-page-1 > .c-cart-buttons > .c-cart-float-r {
    float: none; } }
```

```html
<div class="c-content-box c-size-lg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="c-shop-cart-page-1">
            <div class="row c-cart-table-title">
                <div class="col-md-2 c-cart-image">
                    <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Image</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 c-cart-desc">
                    <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Description</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 c-cart-ref">
                    <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">SKU</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 c-cart-qty">
                    <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Qty</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 c-cart-price">
                    <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Unit Price</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 c-cart-total">
                    <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Total</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 c-cart-remove"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- BEGIN: SHOPPING CART ITEM ROW -->
            
            <div class="row c-cart-table-row">
                <h2 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-theme-bg c-font-white c-cart-item-title c-cart-item-first">Item 1</h2>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 c-cart-image">
                    <img src="../../assets/base/img/content/shop2/24.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-7 c-cart-desc">
                    <h3><a href="shop-product-details-2.html" class="c-font-bold c-theme-link c-font-22 c-font-dark">Winter Jacket</a></h3>
                    <p>Color: Blue</p>
                    <p>Size: S</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-ref">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">SKU</p>
                    <p>120715</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-qty">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">QTY</p>
                    <div class="c-input-group c-spinner">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control c-item-1" value="1">
                        <div class="c-input-group-btn-vertical">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data_input="c-item-1" data-maximum="10"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data_input="c-item-1"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-price">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">Unit Price</p>
                    <p class="c-cart-price c-font-bold">$147.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-total">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">Total</p>
                    <p class="c-cart-price c-font-bold">$147.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 c-cart-remove">
                    <a href="#" class="c-theme-link c-cart-remove-desktop">×</a>
                    <a href="#" class="c-cart-remove-mobile btn c-btn c-btn-md c-btn-square c-btn-red c-btn-border-1x c-font-uppercase">Remove item from Cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END: SHOPPING CART ITEM ROW -->
            <!-- BEGIN: SHOPPING CART ITEM ROW -->
            <div class="row c-cart-table-row">
                <h2 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-theme-bg c-font-white c-cart-item-title">Item 2</h2>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 c-cart-image">
                    <img src="../../assets/base/img/content/shop2/12.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-7 c-cart-desc">
                    <h3><a href="shop-product-details.html" class="c-font-bold c-theme-link c-font-22 c-font-dark">Comfortable Sports Wear Set</a></h3>
                    <p>Color: Grey</p>
                    <p>Size: S</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-ref">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">SKU</p>
                    <p>160815</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-qty">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">QTY</p>
                    <div class="c-input-group c-spinner">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control c-item-2" value="1">
                        <div class="c-input-group-btn-vertical">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data_input="c-item-2" data-maximum="10"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data_input="c-item-2"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-price">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">Unit Price</p>
                    <p class="c-cart-price c-font-bold">$99.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 c-cart-total">
                    <p class="c-cart-sub-title c-theme-font c-font-uppercase c-font-bold">Total</p>
                    <p class="c-cart-price c-font-bold">$99.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 c-cart-remove">
                    <a href="#" class="c-theme-link c-cart-remove-desktop">×</a>
                    <a href="#" class="c-cart-remove-mobile btn c-btn c-btn-md c-btn-square c-btn-red c-btn-border-1x c-font-uppercase">Remove item from Cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END: SHOPPING CART ITEM ROW -->
            <!-- BEGIN: SUBTOTAL ITEM ROW -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="c-cart-subtotal-row c-margin-t-20">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 c-cart-subtotal-border">
                        <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-right c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Subtotal</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 c-cart-subtotal-border">
                        <h3 class="c-font-bold c-font-16">$246.00</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END: SUBTOTAL ITEM ROW -->
            <!-- BEGIN: SUBTOTAL ITEM ROW -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="c-cart-subtotal-row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 c-cart-subtotal-border">
                        <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-right c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Shipping Fee</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 c-cart-subtotal-border">
                        <h3 class="c-font-bold c-font-16">$15.00</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END: SUBTOTAL ITEM ROW -->
            <!-- BEGIN: SUBTOTAL ITEM ROW -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="c-cart-subtotal-row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 c-cart-subtotal-border">
                        <h3 class="c-font-uppercase c-font-bold c-right c-font-16 c-font-grey-2">Grand Total</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 c-cart-subtotal-border">
                        <h3 class="c-font-bold c-font-16">$261.00</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END: SUBTOTAL ITEM ROW -->
            <div class="c-cart-buttons">
                <a href="#" class="btn c-btn btn-lg c-btn-red c-btn-square c-font-white c-font-bold c-font-uppercase c-cart-float-l">Continue Shopping</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn c-btn btn-lg c-theme-btn c-btn-square c-font-white c-font-bold c-font-uppercase c-cart-float-r">Checkout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> -->
</div><!-- END: CONTENT/SHOPS/SHOP-CART-1 -->
```

EDIT: This is the card toggler code mentioning in the comments.

```html
<li class="c-cart-toggler-wrapper">
            <a  href="#" class="c-btn-icon c-cart-toggler"><i class="icon-handbag c-cart-icon"></i> <span class="c-cart-number c-theme-bg">0</span></a>
        </li>
```

Comment: I read all of the text and I didn't see a specific question...

Comment: my mind is pretty fried i've been sat here for 11 hours trying to figure this out, It's difficult for me to explain whilst making sense i'll try again in the morning when my mind is functioning again

Answer (score 0):

The code looks all ok - except you could have created a table using HTML `<table>` and its children tags instead of a complex div setup.

You are running `document.querySelector('.c-cart-toggler-wrapper span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;` to change the content in HTML node but you don't have any tag with the class `.c-cart-toggler-wrapper` in HTML or CSS published here, thus your script will fail.

Is my understanding of your code correct so far?

Comment: Didn’t post that part of the HTML code my specific account problem is passing that data over since I collected it in the cart icon toggles of the homepage (which says how many items you’ve selected, this toggler directs you to that cart.html page) on the cart.html page I’m trying to present the selected products from the catalogue into the cart ready for checking out.

Comment: I've added the html tag for cart toggler in the original post

Comment: I think maybe the way you are storing and fetching product information in local storage seems to be causing the issue. For instance, product variable is an array therefore if you try` product.tag` it will return undefined instead if you try `product[0].tag` it will return 'citizenwatch'.

Therefore, the way the information is fed to localStorage and then retrieving it back is not working based on the syntax being used